# How to collect a classpath of a jar file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, jar

I am trying to understand this batch file which is supposed to collect and set up the classpath to a jar file. I do not understand it at all... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
:----------------------------------------------------------------------------
: collect the class path
:----------------------------------------------------------------------------
…
for /f "delims= tokens=1" %%c in ('dir /B /S /OD
de.msg.pm.potato.sample.plugin.*.jar') do set POTATO_SAMPLE="%%c"
:----------------------------------------------------------------------------
: set the class path
:----------------------------------------------------------------------------
…
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%POTATO_SAMPLE%
```

Comment: Have you tried to read help about it? `FOR /F` processing of a command consists of reading the output from the command one line at a time and then breaking the line up into individual items of data or 'tokens'. The DO command is then executed with the parameter(s) set to the token(s) found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- for /f: loops through text. Options for looping are given in quotes. See: http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html
- dir gives the list of files (listing also subdirectories). See: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntdir.php . This is the 'text' that is given to "for /f" to process.
- %%c is the matched text

This script maybe doesn't work as expected -- the 'set CLASSPATH' should be repeated with each iteration of the loop (now it is repeated only at the end). E.g., by saying:

... do set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"%%c"

inside the loop.